# Dual Irish/US Citizen. Do I need a work visa to move to the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I'm currently employed as a U.S. citizen in the USA.  However, I have dual Irish/US citizenship (and both passports), as my father was born and raised in Cork.  I'd like to request a transfer to the UK from my company (as US subsidiary of a British company).  Do I need a work visa (since I'm currently employed as a U.S. citizen) or can I just work there as an Irish citizen (due to EEA recognition)?  (If I get the transfer, I will work with an immigration attorney to make sure we do it right, but I'd like to "sell" the transfer to them as something easier/cheaper/faster to do if I don't have to get a work visa.)
Thanks!

Comment: You don't mention any family members. If you will be accompanied by any family members there will be other considerations.

Comment: @GerardAshton such as?

Comment: @phoog, such as determining if the relationship qualifies the family member to stay, work, and obtain health services for an extended time/ indefinitely, whether the family member would be able to remain in UK if the original poster returns to the US, obtaining proof of the relationship and, if proof is not in English, an acceptable translation.

Comment: phoog, thank you so much!
GerardAshton, I would bring my husband and 10-year-old daughter (both US citizens) with me. My husband would like to be able to work, but I understand that may not be possible.

Comment: You ought to be able to reclaim this question, perhaps using the [account merge](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) process, after which you'll be able to post comments on your question and its answers. Your husband *will certainly be able to work* if you move to the UK before the end of European Union free movement, which shouldn't be for another year or two. After that, he'll still have the ability to work, but the process will be more burdensome and expensive, and you will have to meet certain financial requirements (which you probably will with your current job).

Comment: @GerardAshton Yes, that is correct, though we now know that the family are husband and daughter, therefore qualifying. Relationship evidence will be birth and marriage certificates, though the daughter is probably also an Irish citizen so only needs a passport. I don't suppose the ability for the family member to remain after the "sponsor" returns to the US is much of an issue on arriving, is it? Would that argue for an application under the immigration rules rather than the free movement regulations?

Comment: Also, your daughter is probably an Irish citizen, too, in which case you can get her an Irish passport instead of applying for a residence card or "settled status" in the UK.  Your husband will want a residence card or "settled status" after arrival in the UK, and may want to get an EEA family permit before going there.

Comment: If the daughter is an Irish citizen, no problem. But in general, with the myriad of different waiting periods from different triggering events, one would want to plan for the possibility that a teenage child likes it there and wants to stay upon reaching age 18, even though the parent comes back to the US.

Comment: @GerardAshton yes, that is also a good point.  If the daughter is not an Irish citizen for some reason, it is certainly something to consider.  The son of a friend of mine is in a similar situation in the US.

Comment: @phoog I am less optimistic than you.  I think EU free movement is quite like to end on October 31st 2019 - but that still gives the OP time to get her husband into the UK.  Fully agree about getting the daughter an Irish passport - best to try and avoid any interactions with the Home Office that can be avoided.

Comment: @MartinBonner as I understand it current law provides that free movement will continue through the end of December 2020 if there is no deal and June 2021 if there is.  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @phoog - You have misunderstood.  Free movement ends immediately if Britain exits without a deal.  I *think* all the EU27+UK+EEFTA have made appropriate regulations so that current residents can stay, but nobody else will be able to come.  Dec 2020 is the end of the transition period when free movement will end under all circumstances.

Comment: @MartinBonner if I understand correctly, EEA registration certificates and residence cards for non-EEA family members remain valid until the end of 2020 if there's no deal.  But you're saying that (without a deal) new arrivals between the departure date and that time will not be covered by the free movement regulations, is that correct?

Comment: @phoog I believe so.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need a work visa.  You are an Irish citizen, and Irish citizens do not need authorization to work in the UK.  The fact that you are also a US citizen who is currently working in the US does not change that.

You also do not need an immigration attorney.  All you need is an Irish passport.

You may want to consult with a financial advisor, however, since the US will continue to require you to report your worldwide income and figure tax on it, though there is an exemption for foreign earned income and for taxes paid to other jurisdictions.  You'll also want to be aware of [FATCA](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/foreign-account-tax-compliance-act-fatca).

Comment: In addition, it is worth noting that the right for Irish citizens to work in the UK without any restriction predates the UK's entry to the EEA and is very likely to continue after the UK's exit from the EEA. (If that ever happens.)  In many ways the UK treats Irish citizens as if independence never happened.

Comment: @MartinBonner indeed.  I thought about mentioning that and decided not to.  But you are right, it should be noted.